# Hover only works on home page

Tags: html, css, hover

my hover only works on first page when page is activated. Only home page change color when I click on it, but other pages dont change color, can you help me? here is code

```
#meni li a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
#meni li.active a {
    color: #000;
}
```

I saw last question about this and I have HTML DOCTYPE on all pages, thanks :)

Comment: are you including the stylesheet in each page?

Comment: yes, i put this on all pages
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">

Comment: can you show us some working demo?

Comment: its on localhost, i can put pictures if that helps?

Comment: And theres no 404 on the other pages? It occurs when you don't prefix the url with a `/` so `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css">`

Comment: can you check in console for errors? if possible add code screen shot.

Comment: here is something, if you need more tell me please, and thank you for help
https://imgur.com/a/7N7QsBw

Comment: Can you check in the console and let me know if there are any errors?

Comment: 0 errors, on all pages.. becouse of this I little hate html and css :)

Comment: use `,` (comma) to separate id's/class for better division in css